# Finding the area of a circle with changing radius?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Hi guys I need some help with a math question I have. It is about a tethered dog and calculating the accessible area of the dog on a given leash. Let us say the pole has dimensions radius=0.1 meters and lets say the leash is legnth=2 meters. The leash of the dog is tied at the very top of the pole (facing north) and it is free to walk around on its leash. You would see that the rope would interact with the rope as the dog walks around the pole in such a way that the leash gets shorter which changes the radius of accessible circle of the dog. How would I go about solving this accessible area for the dog? I know its a circle but the radius (leash) of the circle gets shorter as he walks around the pole as the leash gets tied around it. If you have further questions, always ask me! I would really appreciate some help!!! Thanks everyone!!!  - Skillzz9

Comment: This will help https://socratic.org/questions/a-cow-is-tied-to-a-silo-with-radius-r-by-a-rope-just-long-enough-to-reach-the-op

Comment: What is that you need to find? Just the relationship between change in accessible area wrt. dog walking around the pole by certain angle?

Comment: Can we assume that the rope remains horizontal all the time? By the way, the link mentioned by @Tavish provides you a very good starting point. However, be careful, you need to do some extra work to find the answer to your question.

Comment: What is the height of the pole? Or you assume ground level?

Comment: @MathLover Hey im bassically trying to find the accessible area with a given leash legnth. And the leash starts at 0 radians (facing north) and then can walk around the either clockwise or anti clockwise and by doing that, the dogs leash gets shorter and shorter and im trying to find that area.

Comment: @YNK Hey I dont know what you mean but its bassically the pole stays in a fixed position and the leash is allowed to move around either clockwise or anticlockwise as the dog moves around. And thanks I will take a look at it

Comment: @Moti The height doesnt matter as it is a 2D plane and has no 3D dimensions

Comment: @Tavish thank you that is exactly what I was looking for looks great! Ill try and figure it out

Comment: "You would see that the rope would interact with the rope": what ??? And which rope ???

Comment: "I know its a circle": no.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Are you talking to me?

Comment: "The leash of the dog is tied at the very top of the pole (facing north) and it is free to walk around on its leash" is contradictory with "the radius (leash) of the circle gets shorter as he walks around".

Comment: @YNK: no, I am not.

Answer (score 1):

After the dog has turned by angle $\theta$, the length of the available leash is $(2 - \frac{\theta}{10}) \,$ where $\theta$ is the angle in radians ($n$ complete turns will be $2n \pi$) and $\frac{1}{10}$ is the radius of the pole.

So the accessible area $A = \pi (2 - \frac{\theta}{10})^2$

At $ \theta = 20 \,$ radians, the leash would be completely wrapped around the pole and the accessible area will be zero.

Also, the rate of change in accessible area wrt change in angle at a given angle $\theta$,

$\displaystyle \frac{dA}{d\theta} = - \frac{\pi}{5}(2 - \frac{\theta}{10})$

Comment: Based on your comment, I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know if I did not understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[image: ShortRopeGallery]

$\underline{\mathrm{Introduction}}$

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 0}$ shows the general scenario of tethering a dog to a pole of diameter $2r$ using a rope of length $s$. However, in this answer, we consider a special case of this scenario, in which the rope lies horizontal (i.e. $b = h$), whenever the dog pulls it taut. The rope is tied to the pole at $D$. Dog’s total accessible area is designated as $A$. It is easy to comprehend that the part of this area that lies on the left hand side of the line $DF$ has the shape of a semicircle of radius $s$, which has its center at $D$. Please note that this area is not shown in our diagrams. We denote it as $A_0$, which can be expressed as
$$A_0 = \frac{1}{2}\pi s^2.$$

The rest of the accessible area, which is equal to $A-A_0$, takes the shape of an involute and lies on the right hand side of the line $DF$. When we set on to find a method to calculate this area, we realized that we need to differentiate between two different scenarios. One of them can be called short-rope scenario and the other long-rope scenario. To give the words “short” and “long” mathematically precise meanings, it is necessary to define a dimensionless parameter $\lambda$ as
$$\lambda = \frac{s}{r}, \mathrm{\quad where\quad \infty \ge \lambda \gt 0}.$$

For short-rope cases, we have $\space\pi \ge \lambda \gt 0\space$ and, for long-rope cases, $\space\infty \ge \lambda \ge \pi.\space$ Note that the case $\lambda = \pi$ can be considered as either a short or a long-rope case.

$\underline{Note}$: Values of all angles mentioned in this answer are given in radians. Furthermore, we assume that the reader has gone through the answer given at the link mentioned by @Travis in his comment.

$\mathrm{\underline{Case\space of\space Short\space Rope} \space\left(\pi \ge \lambda \gt 0\right)}$

$\mathrm{Fig.\space 1\space to\space 3}$ show three short-rope cases. The solution of the case depicted in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}$ is described in the answer given at the mentioned link.
As shown in our diagrams, we denote the end point of the involute as $E$ and it is the decisive factor to the size of the sought area. For all short-rope cases, this point lies on the circumference of the circle depicting the pole.
We denote half of the area that lies on the right hand side of the line $DF$ as $A_1$. As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, we need to know the angle $\phi$ in order to determine $A_1$. Since the arc $DE$ is equal to the length of the rope, we shall write,
$$\phi = \frac{s}{r} = \lambda.\tag{1}$$

The area $dA$ of the honeycombed sector-like region $PMNQ$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}$) can be expressed after  approximating it with an isosceles triangle.
$$dA=PMNQ = \frac{1}{2} \left(s-r\theta\right)^2 d\theta$$

When we integrate this, we have,
$$A_1 = \int^\phi_0dA =   \int^\phi_0 \frac{1}{2} \left(s-r\theta\right)^2 d\theta=\frac{1}{6}\phi\left[3s\left(s-r\phi\right)+r^2\phi^2\right], \tag{2}$$

which, can be simplified by replacing $\phi$ using (1) to obtain
$$A_1 = \frac{1}{6}\frac{s^3}{r}.$$

$$\therefore\quad A=A_0 + 2A_1 = \frac{1}{2}\pi s^2 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{s^3}{r} = \frac{1}{6}\frac{s^2}{r}\left(3\pi r+2s\right).\tag{3}$$

For example, if $\lambda = 2$, the dog has the freedom to traverse an area equal to $\space 2.237463 s^2\space$ or $\space 8.94985 r^2$. If the reader need self-convincing, then try his/her hand at solving the case of $\lambda=\pi$, the answer of which is $\frac{5}{6}\pi^3 r^2$.

[image: LongRopeGallery]

[image: AreaCalculation]

$\mathrm{\underline{Case\space of\space Long\space Rope} \space\left(\infty \ge \lambda \ge \pi\right)}$

Several long-rope scenarios are portrayed in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 4\space to\space 6}$. As shown in the diagrams, we define a special point $E$ as the first point of intersection between the involute and the extended $DO$.

There is a special case (of which no sketch is given) with $\lambda = \infty$ (i.e. $r=0$ and $s\gt 0$), in which the involute takes the shape of a semicircle of radius $s$ with its center at $D$. In this instance, the point $E$ is to be found exactly a distance $s$ from $D$ (i.e. $DE=s$). For all the other long-rope cases, we have $DE \lt s$. Because of this, as shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 4}$, the part of each involute lying beyond $E$ (see the hatched area) do not contribute to expand the accessible zone already demarcated by the parts of the two involutes up to $E$.

Now, pay your attention to $\mathrm{Fig.\space 7}$. Here too, we are looking for an angle $\phi$. However, this has nothing to do with the angle $\phi$ that came up in short-rope scenarios. Its size depends on the position of the point $E$. You can obtain this angle by first constructing the tangent from point $E$ to the circle depicting the pole. Then, draw the radius of this circle to pass through the tangential point. The angle between this radius and the line $OD$ is equal to $\phi$, which can have values only in the range
$$\space\pi\ge\phi\gt\frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{4}$$

As shown below, we can derive an expression for $\phi$ by considering the right-angled triangle $EPO$.
$$s-r\phi=r\tan\left(\pi-\phi\right)=-r\tan\left(\phi\right)\quad\rightarrow\quad\frac{s}{r}-\phi+\tan\left(\phi\right)=0 \quad\rightarrow\quad\lambda-\phi+ \tan\left(\phi\right)=0$$

Since this is a nonlinear equation, one has to resort to numerical methods, such as Newton-Raphson method, to obtain the value of $\phi$ within the range specified by (4). An iteration formula based on the said method is given below.
$$\phi_{n+1}=\phi_n-\frac{\lambda-\phi_n}{\tan^2\left(\phi_n\right)}- \frac{1}{\tan\left(\phi_n\right)}, \quad \mathrm{with}\quad \phi_0=1.57079633 \tag{5}$$

To find the area bounded by the involute from $F$ to $E$, the circumference of the pole, and the line segment $BE$, we have to determine areas of two adjacent regions denoted as $A_1$ and $A_2$ separately. As shown below, equation (2) can be used to find the area $A_1$.
$$A_1 = \frac{1}{6}\phi\Bigl[3s\left(s-r\phi\right)+r^2\phi^2\Bigr]$$

As illustrated in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 8}$, the area of $A_2$ can be calculated using a similar method. First, an expression for the area $dA$ of the honeycombed sector-like region $HMNG$ is derived after approximating it with an isosceles triangle. Then, we integrate that expression to obtain $A_2$ as,

$$A_2=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi-\phi}_0 r^2\tan^2\left(\pi-\phi-\omega\right)d\omega=\frac{1}{2}r^2\Bigl[\phi-\tan\left(\phi\right) -\pi\Bigr].$$

$$\therefore A=A_0+2A_1+2A_2=\frac{1}{2}\pi s^2  +\frac{1}{3}\phi\Bigl[3s\left(s-r\phi\right)+r^2\phi^2\Bigr] + r^2\Bigl[\phi-\tan\left(\phi\right) -\pi\Bigr]\tag{6}$$

For example, if $\lambda = 4$, the angle $\phi$ is equal to $2.04325\space rad$. As a consequence, the dog has the freedom to traverse an area equal to $\space 2.80169 s^2\space$ or $\space 44.82708 r^2$.

It is up to the reader to check the formula (6) by applying it to the two cases $\lambda=\pi$ and $\lambda=\infty$. The latter case, where $r=0$, is bit tricky and, if the reader is able to show that the accessible area is equal to $\pi s^2$, then he/she has mastered the method.

$\mathrm{\underline{Additional\space of\space Information}}$

[image: muvslambda]

It is possible to express the total accessible area as $A=\mu s^2$, where $\mu$ is a function of $\lambda$. $\mathrm{Fig.\space 9}$ shows how $\mu$ varies with $\lambda$ for a given length of a rope. It is easy to see that, as $\lambda$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, the total accessible area $A$ monotonically increases from $\frac{1}{2}\pi s^2$ to $\pi s^2$.